# Data gets skewed when re-adding it into the table of contents

Tags: qgis, vector, accuracy

some of my data gets re-align every time i re-add it in within the QGIS Table of contents ( like a good 5-10 feet off). I have no idea what could be the cause, I may have the given layer in a different projection compared to the basemap  but i don't think that is the case. suggestions?

Comment: What basemap are you using?

Comment: ... and what CRS is the data layer in?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the CRS of your vector layer then add that to a *new* map document. Next, open the **layer** properties and define the CRS, if necessary. After that, make sure that on-the-fly projection is enabled in the **document** properties, then add your basemap. All should line up if your basemap's projection is known and/or if you are using a served raster.

Comment: its strange. so i'm working with the zoning vector layer(the one that wasn't matching up), but it has a different projection than my basemap and the other vector layers. When i make the same CRS as the other basemap layers for the zone layer, it doesn't show up or its way out in the middle of nowhere. I do have on-the-fly projection enabled in both cases.

Comment: Given what you describe in your comment, my guess is the CRS was defined incorrectly at the start; thus, any subsequent reprojection will be incorrect. Have you reached out to the data provider/creator to make sure you know the CRS? And have you tried loading all your vector layers without the basemap - if so, do they all line up then? An additional note, if you're doing any analyses among your various vector layers, a best practice is to have them all in the same CRS. [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232567/when-to-enable-on-the-fly-crs-transformation-in-qgis-when-to-turn-it-off?rq=1]